# How can I read out name of instagram accounts (2019) who liked or commented my post with Graph-API, 3rd-party API or parsing?

Tags: parsing, facebook-graph-api, comments, instagram-graph-api

I want to have a list of people who liked or commented my posts. These are all informations which are not critically regarding GDPR because everybody can see these informations. But the problem is that its not possible anymore to use Instagram API like in 2017:

```
> https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{mediaID}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

So I am looking for other solutions like parsing or third party APIs.
Would be happy if anybody can help me.

I already tried Instagram API and Graph-API for business accounts but its not working. So I tried to parse the Instagram page for my post. 
But Instagram only show a 20 likes list and you have scroll for the next 20 likes and so on. Same problem with comments.

I think there have to be some already done solutions for this problem, so I want you to ask for some help.

Comment: "not critically regarding GDPR because everybody can see these informations" - that does not automatically mean you are allowed to get/use/store the data without user consent...and scraping is most likely not allowed on instagram. it´s not allowed on facebook, and instagram is owned by facebook.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Unfortunatelly its not allowed by Instagrams API anymore but it was until 2017 and Instagram still provides these informations because they are not critically and everybody can read them. Its possible to see every username from people who liked any picture.
For me its important to see who liked my post and I can do it manually while using Instagram but if you have more than 100 or 1000 likes its time consuming so as an ingenieur I want to set up an automatism :-) and I think there have to be people who already had the same problem.

Comment: again, just because something is public and visible, does not mean you are allowed to do something with it. you CAN get comments with the new api, but not with names, only with timestamp and message. so i assume it´s for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I know that Instagram dont want people easily to read out the names of likers. Thats why I was asking if someone can help me or give me some hints to do it. I dont want to scrape informations to set up a database of user informations to sell them and I assume even this could be legal but I am not a lawyer. I only want to use it private and automate sth. what I am doing at the moment manually. Its similar to a simple parsing question and I know that stackoverflow also helps for example for jailbreak questions and this is definitely forbidden by apple.

Comment: no, that would definitely not be legal, to sell user information. that would be weird ;) - so what exactly do you want to automate? it would help a lot to know the exact use case.